# Testing that job has been enqueued multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5.1

How can I write spec to test that my method enqueues some ActiveJob `n` times?

I know that I can check if job has been enqueued by

```
expect {
  UploadBackupsJob.perform_later
}.to have_enqueued_job(UploadBackupsJob)
```

My method is working on array of `n` elements and should enqueue ActiveJob for each element of this array.

Comment: dammit, I found a better version. I'll go answer there instead.

Comment: Marcin, check out my answer on the linked question (also, that's why you should post good complete questions at a first try).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.